# How to include the schema when scripting SQL Server stored procedures?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, smo

I am trying to force SMO to schema qualify object names for stored procedures, UDFs and views, but for some reason it doesn't work.  I have got a stored procedure without a schema and need to have the default schema pre-pended to it:

I have this code:

```
var procs = from sp in _smoDB.StoredProcedures.OfType<StoredProcedure>()
              where !sp.IsSystemObject && !sp.IsEncrypted
              select sp;

foreach ( StoredProcedure sproc in procs ) {

    var script = sproc.Script( ScriptOption.SchemaQualify );
    var scriptText = script[3];

}
```

When I access the script text it isn't putting the schema name (dbo) in front of the stored prcocedure.  Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't worked with SMO in 2008/R2 (only 2005), so I may be missing something, but here's what's I'd try:

```
var procs = from sp in _smoDB.StoredProcedures.OfType<StoredProcedure>()
            where !sp.IsSystemObject && !sp.IsEncrypted               
            select sp; 

var options = new ScriptOptions();         // reusable ScriptOptions object
options.SchemaQualify = true;
options.EnforceScriptingOptions = true;    // surprise!
foreach ( StoredProcedure sproc in procs ) 
{
    var script = sproc.Script( options );     
    var scriptText = script[3];  
}
```

(I haven't tested this)

I'm guessing the stored procedure was originally created without specifying the schema, and that is what is being scripted.  To get a schema-qualified script, you'll need to enforce the scripting options and will lose any comments and formatting (here's the article from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions.enforcescriptingoptions.aspx)).

I believe this will apply to Views and Functions as well.

Comment: Setting the `.EnforceScriptingOptons = True` scripting option has done the trick.  Thanks for this!